# Issues making a connection secure using AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl, amazon-elb

We are hosting a website using the EC2 service on Amazon Web Services. The website is currently up and running but the issue is we are trying to make the connection secure by applying a certificate using the AWS Certificate Manager. But for whatever reason using several different browsers the connection keeps saying it’s not secure. Here is my set up; please let me know if I’m missing anything thank you. Please note additional pictures are below due to picture limitations.

[VPC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX4ld.png)

[VPC ACL Inbound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVQfN.png)

[VPC ACL Outbound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bABNG.png)

[VPC Routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOw8N.png)

[ELB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm1ee.png)

[ELB Inbound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy9GT.jpg)

[ELB Outbound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfZUE.png)

[ELB listeners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn5C8.png)

Comment: Target group port 80 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnfKb.png  Target group port 443 https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8i42.png  SSL Certificate https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQtQX.png  EC2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmtQw.jpg  EC2 Inbound https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvEBX.png  EC2 Outbound https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YlJR.png

Comment: A note - to diagnose SSL issues the domain name is essential. It was in your screenshots so I posted it in my answer, but it's edited out. The links still reveal your domain name, but they could be removed if you like.

Comment: is it possible to redirect port 80 traffic to port 443 using ELB?

Answer (score 3):

I put your domain name "test.example.com" into an [SSL testing tool](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html)  which told me it was a certificate name mismatch.

The certificate issued is for

```
*.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com
```

You need to look at how you got your certificate and how it's associated with your load balancer.

Comment: So my domain is healthy now but no changes have occured